# Social share buttons in own timeline post

Tags: facebook, share, social-networking

I have a web wrote in PHP and it has a sort of timeline with posts and comments, I want to put the social media share buttons for each post that my timeline has, it is possible?

I took a look website as https://www.addthis.com/ but that plugin share the page where it is present. I wanted share every post on the same page.

Thanks for any suggest.

Comment: You need to have a unique url to each post

Comment: Thanks I already have a unique url for each post if need it, but where should I put that?